unexpected packages are slowing down the app - Android
I created a foreground sticky service, I am learning to develop android apps
The service is nothing but to print the time for every 5 sec and check the data from the server
when the service is running, i got these logs in adb logcat
11-30 17:26:03.809  5070  5070 D PkgDataHelper: getGamePkgData(). org.test.myapp
11-30 17:26:03.812  5070  5070 D GameManagerService: identifyGamePackage. org.test.myapp, mCurrentUserId: 0, callerUserId: 0
11-30 17:26:03.812  5070  5070 D PkgDataHelper: getGamePkgData(). org.test.myapp
11-30 17:26:04.245  5070 12125 D GameManagerService: identifyGamePackage. org.test.myapp, mCurrentUserId: 0, callerUserId: 0
11-30 17:26:04.245  5070 12125 D PkgDataHelper: getGamePkgData(). org.test.myapp
11-30 17:26:04.605  5410  5410 D PluginAODManager: onNotificationInfoUpdated() 0|org.test.myapp|1|null|10683
11-30 17:26:04.689  5410  5410 D PluginAODManager: onNotificationInfoUpdated() 0|org.test.myapp|1|null|10683
11-30 17:26:08.149  5410  5410 D PluginAODManager: onNotificationInfoUpdated() 0|org.test.myapp|1|null|10683




11-30 17:52:46.129  4265  4287 I LogFromService: [INFO   ] [myapp_service] loop start ###################!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
11-30 17:52:46.152  5070  7417 D SecContentProvider: called from org.test.myapp
11-30 17:52:46.300  5410  5410 D PluginAODManager: onNotificationInfoUpdated() 0|org.test.myapp|1|null|10684
11-30 17:52:47.486  5070  7367 D SecContentProvider: called from org.test.myapp
11-30 17:52:47.504  4265  5477 I LogFromService: [INFO   ] [myapp_service] pop-data - 4
11-30 17:52:49.305  5070  5070 D GameManagerService: identifyGamePackage. org.test.myapp, mCurrentUserId: 0, callerUserId: 0
11-30 17:52:49.305  5070  5070 D PkgDataHelper: getGamePkgData(). org.test.myapp
11-30 17:52:49.494  5410  5410 D PluginAODManager: onNotificationInfoUpdated() 0|org.test.myapp|1|null|10684
11-30 17:52:55.334  5070 12125 D GameManagerService: identifyGamePackage. org.test.myapp, mCurrentUserId: 0, callerUserId: 0
11-30 17:52:55.334  5070 12125 D PkgDataHelper: getGamePkgData(). org.test.myapp
11-30 17:52:55.907  5410  5410 D PluginAODManager: onNotificationInfoUpdated() 0|org.test.myapp|1|null|10684
11-30 17:52:58.171  4265  4287 I LogFromService: [INFO   ] [myapp_service] loop start ###################!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

11-30 18:29:15.316  5410  5410 D PluginAODManager: onNotificationInfoUpdated() 0|org.test.myapp|1|null|10685
11-30 18:29:18.918  5410  5410 D PluginAODManager: onNotificationInfoUpdated() 0|org.test.myapp|1|null|10685
11-30 18:29:24.049  5410  5410 D PluginAODManager: onNotificationInfoUpdated() 0|org.test.myapp|1|null|10685

11-30 18:37:36.619  5410  5410 D PluginAODManager: onNotificationInfoUpdated() 0|org.test.myapp|1|null|10685
11-30 18:37:36.714  5410  5410 D PluginAODManager: onNotificationInfoUpdated() 0|org.test.myapp|1|null|10685
11-30 18:37:36.980  5410  5410 D PluginAODManager: onNotificationInfoUpdated() 0|org.test.myapp|1|null|10685

11-30 18:38:10.015  5070  5485 D SecContentProvider: called from org.test.myapp


11-30 18:39:48.181 12016 12038 I LogFromService: [INFO   ] [myapp_service] loop start ###################!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
11-30 18:39:48.193  5070  7418 D SecContentProvider: called from org.test.myapp
11-30 18:39:49.738  5070  7419 D SecContentProvider: called from org.test.myapp
11-30 18:39:49.745 12016 16245 I LogFromService: [INFO   ] pop_data key - 3_17329709659466455
11-30 18:39:49.755 12016 16245 I LogFromService: [INFO   ] [myapp_service] pop-data - 17
11-30 18:39:50.060  5410  5410 D PluginAODManager: onNotificationInfoUpdated() 0|org.test.myapp|1|null|10685
11-30 18:39:51.265  5410  5410 D PluginAODManager: onNotificationInfoUpdated() 0|org.test.myapp|1|null|10685
11-30 18:39:51.674  5410  5410 D PluginAODManager: onNotificationInfoUpdated() 0|org.test.myapp|1|null|10685
11-30 18:39:52.378  5410  5410 D PluginAODManager: onNotificationInfoUpdated() 0|org.test.myapp|1|null|10685
11-30 18:39:52.549 12016 12038 I LogFromService: [INFO   ] [myapp_service] loop completed - 4.368592739105225
11-30 17:26:08.149  5410  5410 D PluginAODManager: onNotificationInfoUpdated() 0|org.test.dynamic_wallpaper|1|null|10683

these logs are occurred in between the loop and these logs are literally slowing down the loop
what are these logs - SecContentProvider, GameManagerService, PkgDataHelper, PluginAODManager, onNotificationInfoUpdated
how to stop these logs, could you help me on this, thanks

It is HIGHLY unlikely that other apps are significantly slowing down such a simple service.  Phones have more than 1 core, and they multitask well.  More likely your code is either not doing what you think it is, doing something incorrectly, or taking up too much time itself.  But since you didn't post your code, we can't help you with it.
